# Formula for potential for 2 coaxial tubes

Tags: electromagnetism, homework-and-exercises, potential

Could someone remind me of the formula for potential function for a system consisting of 2 coaxial tubes maintained at a fixed potential difference and the in between medium has uniform conductivity $c$? (I have forgotten how to calculate these things, have been a long time since high school!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula:$$V(r)=V_0\frac{(r-r_1)(r_1r_2)}{(r_2-r_1)(r_1r)}$$

How to derive: I found the boundary value of current  by integration, substituted in ohm's law, and integrated once more.

Remember that current varies inversely to r.

Comment: I've not cancelled the $r_1$ on purpose, it makes the origin of the equation more apparent.

Comment: And you can easily see that pd is $\propto \Delta\frac{1}{r}$